# How reducing languages work?

Tags: automata, undecidability

I am reading Automata Theory book by Hopcroft, Motwani and Ullman 2nd ed.
In this book, there are these sentences:

> In general, if we have an algorithm to convert instances of a problem $P_1$ to instances of a problem $P_2$ that have the same answer, then we say that $P_1$ * reduces to *$P_2$. We can use this proof to show that $P_2$ is at least as hard as $P_1$. Thus, if $P_1$ is not recursive, then $P_2$ cannot be recursive. If $P_2$ is non-RE, then $P_1$ cannot be RE.

I am quite confused due to last statement above because the book further states the following theorem:

> If there is a reduction from $P_1$ to $P_2$, then:
>
> - If $P_1$  is undecidable then so is $P_2$.
> - If $P_1$ is non-RE, then so is $P_2$.

I dont know whether I should feel that the last statement above contradicts with the last statement in the first paragraph. So whats true?

> If $P_2$ is non-RE, then $P_1$ cannot be RE.

Or

> If $P_1$ is non-RE, then so is $P_2$.

Or both mean the same and I am unnecessarily thinking that they are contradicting each other unnecessarily? Or the book is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will reduce $P_1$ to $P_2$ if you know something "bad" about $P_1$, and you want to see if this extends to $P_2$.

It should read "If $P_1$ is non-RE, $P_2$ cannot be RE". If it is in the book, it's a typo.

Comment: thanks for confirmation, so its always source language (the one that we reduce) whose properties get translated to the destination language (the one to which we reduce)...